Check if file is open for writing by another task
Is it possible (in Python under Linux) to determine whether a file is still being written and hasn't been closed yet?
I'm trying to write data to a cache (file) which isn't quite complete yet when other processes are already accessing it. The file/cache then appears corrupted to the processes reading it.

You could check the modification timestamp on the file, and if it's very recent (say less than a minute old), it might be safe to assume the file is still being written.

What is the scenario? You have two answers below which address what you ask about. However, I have a feeling that you have a much more fundamental design problem which can't be fully covered by the suggested approaches. Generally separate processes must somehow be synchronized when writing to a shared resource, in order to prevent race conditions. How to do that depends on the scenario, hence my question.

The non-standard psutil module will help you find out if a file is open although not its mode

@JohnGordon timestamp checking is too flaky (this file is written in a few ms or s).

@UlrichEckhardt "separate processes must somehow be synchronized when writing to a shared resource" - that's not the issue as writing is synchronised. 1 process is writing, multiple ones are reading. The reading is intentionally not synchronised (as it is meant to happen concurrently).

@SIGHUP hmm... I'd like to avoid any additional packages, but good to know that it's possible with psutil.

Inspired by @Hipo's answer, I went with a solution that creates a temporary file which marks the writer processes as busy. If this file exists, then the readers don't read. Once the writer process is finished, it deleted this temporary file.
I found this easier than setting fcntl.LOCK_EX on the written file as I couldn't find a way to read this flag in the reader processes.
def lock(fname):
    fname = '%s.lock' % fname
    assert not os.path.exists(fname), '%s already exists.' % fname
    open(fname, 'w').close()


def is_locked(fname):
    fname = '%s.lock' % fname
    return os.path.exists(fname)


def unlock(fname):
    fname = '%s.lock' % fname
    os.remove(fname)


If you don't have control over the process writing to the cache file, you can wait until all file descriptors to the file are closed by looking at the symbolic links in /proc/<pid>/fd. If you know the pid of the writer, you can check if it has the file open with something like:
import os

def check_pid_for_file(pid, filename):
    target_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
    fd_dir = f'/proc/{pid}/fd'
    
    try:
        for fd in os.listdir(fd_dir):
            if os.path.realpath(os.path.join(fd_dir, fd)) == target_path:
                return True
    except OSError:
        pass
    
    return False


Unfortunately, I don't know the PID of the writer in the reading processes. I can however control the writing process.

First part of the solution, you can lock the file while you are writing and prevent the other process changing it.
python doc on fcntl
import fcntl
   import os

   def lock_file(file_path):
       fd = os.open(file_path, os.O_RDWR)
       fcntl.flock(fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
       return fd

   def unlock_file(fd):
       fcntl.flock(fd, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
       os.close(fd)

The second part of the solution is to prevent your access before the other process finish. A possible solution is listening to system inotify events.
python inotify package
or another package pyinotify.
 import inotify.adapters

   def _main():
       i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

       # Add a watch on the directory or file
       i.add_watch('/path/to/your/file_or_directory')

       for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
           (_, type_names, path, filename) = event
           if 'IN_CLOSE_WRITE' in type_names:
               print(f"File {filename} has been closed after writing.")


The lock is a great idea. It would convey that the file is still written (for any reading process). How can I test (in another process) if LOCK_EX is being set. I'm not so much after the locking itself (mutual exclusion for write processes is handled in my application), but conveying that the file hasn't been fully written (which I would use LOCK_EX for).

If checking LOCK_EX is not possible, I might go down the path of creating an additional <file_path>.lock file which I use in the reading processes to determine whether or not the file has been written completely.

The provided code demos how to listen to event. I didn't find a way to read current state.
